Pomp and circumstance march no. 1 Edward Elgar F horn and trumpet written without key signature - which C was it transposed to?
I am transcribing Edward Elgar's Pomp and Circumstance March no. 1 in Musescore. Here is the part of the score was puzzling me until I read this question.

You can see that the Horn and Trumpet are written with a C key signature. They both transpose to F in this score. Normally, a score in D major should be written in A major for a F horn/trumpet. Which C was the A transposed to? The C above or below the A? I hit a brick wall here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I believe that the F transposition was written out on the score, accidentals were needed to account for the C key signature.

Both horn in F and trumpet in F sound a perfect fifth below the written pitch. So if middle C is written in a part, the audience will hear the F below middle C when the player plays.
In the score excerpt shown, everyone who plays in the first measure is producing a concert Eb as their first note. In particular, the high horns are producing Eb right above middle C and the low horns are producing the Eb below middle C (an octave below the high horns).
I think asking “which C was the A transposed to” suggests you have broader confusion about how this works.
The horn and trumpet are not written in the key of C in this excerpt. They are written in A with no key signature. In this style of music, instead of writing key signatures, horn and trumpet parts have the accidentals written into the music. That means for music written in A, every time a C, F, or G is written in the part, it will have a sharp in front of it (the first time each measure), instead of putting those sharps in the key signature.
